# why I'm not getting the right shape

Tags: python, numpy, append

```
import numpy as np
# load all images in a directory
from os import listdir
from matplotlib import image
# load all images in a directory
loaded_images = list()
path='/content/IDC_regular_ps50_idx5'
for big_folder in listdir(path):
    for folder in listdir(path + '/' + big_folder  ):
        for filename in listdir(path + '/' + big_folder + '/' + folder):
          # load image
          img_data = image.imread(path + '/' + big_folder +'/' + folder + '/' +filename)
          # store loaded image
          loaded_images.append(np.vstack(img_data))
          #print('> loaded %s %s' % (filename, img_data.shape))
```

when i press `np.array(loaded_images).shape` I'm getting (277524) which is the numbers of images , what I desire is the 4D (277524 , 3 , 50 , 50 ) .
note : when I do `loaded_images[i].shape` I get (3 , 50 ,50 )

Comment: 1. `(277,524 , 3 , 50 , 50 )` is 5D. 2. What exactly are you expecting `np.vstack` to do when you just give it the single `img_data` at a time? 3. If you dump each processed image into a single flat `list` first, how exactly are you intending for `np.array` to arrange those items into multiple dimensions?  4. Why should we expect every (sub)folder to contain the same number of images of the same size, anyhow?

Comment: 4.the sub folders doesn't contain the same number of images but they do have the same size , 3. what else  should I append my processed images to ? 1. sorry its my bad just Edit it .

Comment: At least one of the images in the list has a different shape.

Comment: @hpaulj thanks for your comment , i added    `if img_data.shape !=(50, 50, 3): continue` to check for the right shape but still `np.array(loaded_images).shape` is (277524,) instead of (277524, 50, 50, 3)

Comment: Try `np.stack(loaded_images)`